# Prestashop export from 1.5 to 1.7

Tags: mysql, csv, prestashop, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

I just received access to a Prestashop v1.5.4.1 which is like completely ruined (the guys before destroyed it big time). There are a lot of products and categories. We would like to export them to the new one (1.7.2.4).

The thing is, I can actually export products from the old one, but there are not a lot of informations in the CSV (ID, photo, name, ref, category, price without taxe, including taxes, quantity, statut and that's it). AND, I can't export categories (the button doesn't actually work) and I can't export attributs and values, etc...

My question is : Is there another way to export stuff, like nearly every text infos and import them to the new one ? Since it's CSV, can I export it from phpmyadmin and then export it ? While I'm asking the question I guess I just found the answer.. But hey, still asking :)

I tried to install 1-clickUpdate, it works (with many difficulties) but doesn't install new version. And, I'd rather start a new fresh prestashop without all the addons that are useless and some stuff that I don't even know how they are working.

Thanks a lot !

**EDIT 11/04**

Found a [free module](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/37900-free-module-products-export-module-v260-updated-13082017/) (more explanations in the answers)

Comment: About the phpmyadmin solution, that's crazy, I would have to cross many tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [free export module](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/37900-free-module-products-export-module-v260-updated-13082017/) that worked pretty well. I can't export attributes but it does more than expected and easy to use. I just had to delete html code from the CSV manually and clean a bit (like deleting html tags or stuff like that that prestashop didn't read to well while importing).

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Prestashop Store Manager](https://www.prestashopmanager.com/). It's a commercial product (a Windows application) and you can try their trial version if it works on your ruined store. I am not affiliated with them but I recommend their product because our customers were very satisfied with it.

You will be able to import/export nearly everything including [categories](http://store-manager-for-prestashop-documentation.emagicone.com/prestashop-category-management/export-prestashop-categories).

Comment: Thanks for it, but I'm on a mac :(